# Access VBA accessing element of recordset

Tags: vba, ms-access, recordset

How do I select the actual variable if the recordset is JOINed from to tables?

```
 Dim db As DAO.Database
 Set db = CurrentDb
 Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
 Set rs = Currentdb.OpenRecordset("SELECT tableA.data, tableB.data “ & _
                                  “FROM tabelA INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.ID = tableB.xyz”)

 Debug.Print (srs!tableA.data) ' does not work
```

Yes, data could be an element of tableA or B ... but how to specify?

THank you, Reinhard

Workaround like "as TabA_data" works but there must be a more elegant solution?

Comment: The alias is certainly the most elegant solution for this situation (at least if you can't rename the fields). :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you do indeed have two fields in different tables with the same name, then you have several options.

- Firstly, you could actually name the fields differently in the tables. For example, `Address` in table `Customer` could become `CustomerAddress` and `Address` in `Supplier` could be `SupplierAddress`. This is probably the approach that I would recommend, as it prevents ambiguity/confusion.
- Secondly, as you have mentioned, you could alias the field names in the query.
- Finally, you could refer to the fields in the recordset by their position:

```
Debug.Print rs(0)  ' Recordsets are 0-indexed, so this returns the first field
```

I'm not keen on doing this, as if extra fields are introduced into the recordset, this may no longer work.

Comment: Accessing fields of recordsets by their index does definitely still work. `rs.fields(0)` will return the first field in the recordset.

Comment: What I meant, is if you originally `SELECT FieldA, FieldB`, and then alter the SQL to be `SELECT FieldA, FieldC, FieldB`, `rs(1)` will now return data for FieldC rather than FieldB.

Comment: I see, sorry for the confusion.